# lerna not generating node_module in packages

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json, lerna, monorepo

I have a monorepo with Lerna and typescript with a basic structure

```
- root 
  package.json
  - packages
      package-A
         package.json
         src
      package-B
         package.json
         src
```

The root package.json tsconfig configuration

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "@namespace/*": [
        "packages/*/src"
      ]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

The tsconfig of each package looks like

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Now when I run `lerna bootstrap` or `lerna boostrap --hoist` all dependencies from package A and package B go to the root module. No node_modules folder gets generated at the packages level.

Is this the normal behaviour?

Also in development, in the packages I have a nodemon script which runs `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts`

When I run nodemon directly from the command line, I get

```
sh: ts-node: command not found
[nodemon] failed to start process, "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts" exec not found
```

But when I add it as a script to the packages's package.json `"start:dev": "nodemon"` and I do `npm run start:dev` then it works.

It's like in a way nodemon complains about not finding the binary for `ts-node` in the package's node_modules/.bin (since it's not generated), but when I run it with `start:dev` it fetches it from the root node_modules..?

Did I miss something in the setup?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: also the same issue any fix ?